# Angular Typescript - waiting for a value from a popup dialog

Tags: html, angular, typescript, wait

I have an html button that when pressed, calls a function that sets a 'display' boolean to true which makes a popup dialog box appear where the user can choose a name from a list of names. Choosing a name sets a 'selectedName' variable to the selected name.

Here's my problem - the same function that I originally call to display the popup dialog needs to do some more processing with the selected name - I would like to do all of this in a single function call. Something like this:

```
// Called by pressing an HTML button
getSelectedName() {
    display = true; // makes dialog popup appear

    // Wait for user to select a name and press a 'Confirm' button 
    // within the dialog popup

    // Once the user has selected a name, do something with it
    var person: Person;
    person.name = selectedName;
}
```

The popup dialog has Confirm/Cancel buttons - is there anyway to make the above function wait for the user to click the Confirm button, then continue on in the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a promise that resolves once the user clicks confirm, then do any work you need only once that promise is resolved.

```
// Called by pressing an HTML button
getSelectedName() {
    display = true; // makes dialog popup appear

    // Create a promise that resolves when button is clicked.
    const buttonPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        const button = document.getElementById("my-confirm-button");
        const resolver = () => {
            resolve();
            button.removeEventListener("click", resolver);
        }

        button.addEventListener("click", resolver);
    });
    

    // Once the user has selected a name, do something with it       
    buttonPromise.then(() => {
        var person: Person;
        person.name = selectedName;
    })
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to wait for a value change instead of a button click?

Comment: Sure. Get the element who's value will be changing instead of the button, then instead of a click listener, change it to a 'change' listener. So: `const input = document.getElementById("my-input");` and then change add/remove listener to `input.addEventListener("change", resolver)`. However, note that the promise will resolve on the first change event, and further changes won't do anything. If you want code to run on any change, put it inside the event listener itself instead of using a promise.

Comment: Why do you first remove the event listener, and then add it back again?

Comment: @CRice Thanks. Also, I noticed that you declared `buttonPromise`, but then later referred to it as `clickPromise`. That might be confusing to some readers.

Comment: @CRice Can you also explain the logic behind removing the event listener, returning, and adding it again?

Comment: @Kingamere Ah actually I think I was right to omit the return statement after all. If you look closely you'll note that the removal happens only when the `resovler` function is called by the event listener. So the listener will remove itself the first time it is called. Since the removal is part of a different function, there is no adding it "again", it is only added one time per call to `getSelectedName`. Thanks for catching that other typo though.